# C# Pass textbox content via CommandArgument in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, commandargument

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Cartridges" runat="server" onitemcommand="Cartridges_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p class="cartprice"><%#String.Format("{0:C}", Eval("Price"))%></p>
        <hr class="hr4" /> 
        <p class="cartqty">QTY <asp:TextBox ID="cartQty" Text="0" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> </p>
        <div class="cartbuy2"><asp:LinkButton ID="buy" runat="server" CommandName="AddtoCart" CommandArgument=<%#Eval("cartID") %> Text="Buy"></asp:LinkButton></div>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

How can I pass the textbox value within CommandArgument? Sorry totally lost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FindControl to get other items in the repeater Item.  For Example:

```
 protected void repeater_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
 {
      LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
      string textBoxValue = ((TextBox)lb.Parent.FindControl("cartQty")).Text;         
 }
```

Comment: @ComfortablyNumb: you asked for `How can I pass the textbox value within CommandArgument?` and this is not an answer for this specific question.
but anyway, good point for you @WesGrant :)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try: `CommandArgument='<%#Eval("cartID") %>'`

this is different from yours as it is surrounded by a single quote, I guess this is the correct syntax.

Comment: <asp:LinkButton ID="buy" runat="server" CommandName="AddtoCart" CommandArgument=<%#Eval("cartID") %> Text="Buy"></asp:LinkButton></div>

Comment: I know what he tried, and again, mine is different. notice the single quote here: `'<%#Eval("cartID") %>'`

Comment: <%#Eval("cartID") %> is alreay there it was the cartQty value I wanted to pick up as well as the cartID.

Comment: @Muhammed: thanks for your vote, and sorry for misunderstanding your first comment :).

Comment: Thank you for you help on the syntax

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind the cartId to the linkbutton onItemDataBound and then access it onItemCommand, I have modified code for you, give this a go

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Cartridges" runat="server" onitemcommand="Repeater_OnItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="Repeater_OnItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <p class="cartprice"><%#String.Format("{0:C}", Eval("Price"))%></p>
    <hr class="hr4" /> 
    <p class="cartqty">QTY <asp:TextBox ID="cartQty" Text="0" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> </p>
    <div class="cartbuy2"><asp:LinkButton ID="buy" runat="server" CommandName="AddtoCart" Text="Buy"></asp:LinkButton></div>
```

your onItemdatabound should look like this

```
 protected void Repeater_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {

        //your code...

          LinkButton add = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("buy");
                  add.CommandArgument = cartID.ToString();

    }
```

and then you can access the text box on item command like this

```
 protected void Repeater_OnItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "AddtoCart")
            {
                LinkButton btnEdit = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
                if (btnEdit != null)
                {
                    string editId = btnEdit.CommandArgument;
                    string text = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("cartQty")).Text;
                    //do some stuff with your cartid and quantity
                }
            }
}
```

You can also extend your code with edit/delete command arguments by adding more linkbuttons and binding them to the correct command and then accessing them in on item command
Thanks